# error in .tbl_df unused arguments in RStudio

Tags: r, data.table

I want to aggregate my data grouped by `Invoice No`, so I used the following code:

```
AggByInvNo <- as.data.frame(mydata[, j=list(num_of_Product= length(Description), 
                                            num_of_Quantity = sum(Quantity), 
                                            totalPrice= sum(TotalPrice)),
                            by = list(InvoiceNo, Country)])
```

but it doesn't work.

Error message:

```
Error in `[.tbl_df`(mydata, , j = list(num_of_Product = length(Description),  : 
unused argument (by = list(InvoiceNo, Country))
```

I used this code with the same data set and it had worked.
I use `data.table`.

Comment: Looks like `mydata` is `tbl_df` and not a `data.table`. Cast to `data.table` first with `setDT`.

Comment: it works now thank you very much LyzandeR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setDT(data, keep.rownames=TRUE, key=NULL, check.names=FALSE)
```